# Laravel 4 Error Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have this code in my file Routes.php

Route::controller('/cargo/prueba','PruebaController');

and my file PruebaController have this:

```
<?php
class PruebaController extends BaseController {
    protected $layout = 'layouts.master';
    public function getTipo(){
        //$datos=TipoUsuario::all();
        return View::make('cargo.prueba.pbd');
    }
}
```

I need the solution to this problem please!

Comment: What URL are you accessing ? Also please fix the code formatting and don't use `inline code` (with backquotes) for multi-line code, indent all of it by 4 spaces instead (or just select it and press the curly braces button in the editor's toolbar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your root `URL` in the route declaration is `/cargo/prueba` so to invoke the `getTipo()` method in `PruebaController` controller, your `URL` would be this:

```
yourdomain.com/cargo/prueba/tipo
```

So if you run `php artisan routes` from terminal/command prompt then you would find the answer; which will show you the `URL` to access your method and it's given below:

```
URL                                                      | Action
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
cargo/prueba/tipo/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?} | PruebaController@getTipo
```

So the class should be something like this:

```
class PruebaController extends BaseController {

    public function getTipo(){

    }
}
```